# How to command siri to start recording my voice?

Tags: ipad, siri, voice-dictation, voice-memo

On an iPad Pro with iPadOS 15.0.2, how do I tell Siri to start recording my voice? When I say “Siri, record a voice memo”, it opens voice memo, but I still need to push the record button for the recording to start. But sometimes I want to record my voice while I am not very close to my iPad, so I want a way to tell iPad to start recording without needing me to push the record button.